# Is there a way to make Gmail check an IMAP email account?

Tags: gmail, imap

Is there a way or any 3rd party service to make Gmail check an IMAP email account?

Answer (score 1):

Are you not able to just have the IMAP account forward to gmail?

Comment: I believe that's the only way at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could setup a regular mail client, like Thunderbird, to check your IMAP account, and then create a filter that forwards all mail to your gmail account. This does require you to have Thunderbird running at all times though.

[How to setup filters in Thunderbird](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filters_%28Thunderbird%29)